# Show that $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \mu(\{x : |f_n(x) - f(x)| > \epsilon\}) < \infty$ implies $f_n \to f$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Show that $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \mu(\{x : |f_n(x) - f(x)| > \epsilon\}) < \infty$ implies $f_n \to f$ a.e, where $f_n$ and $f$ are measurable functions.

My attempt: The Borel Cantelli lemma gives us that almost all $x$ are in at most finitely many $A_n = \{x : |f_n(x) - f(x)| > \epsilon\}$, so, for each $x$, there exists some $N$ such that for all $n \ge N$, $|f_n(x) - f(x)| \le \epsilon$. Since this is true for all $\epsilon$, we let $\epsilon$ go to zero, and we are done.

This is what I have, but someone told me that I have an issue with countability, and that in order to fix it, I need to consider $\epsilon = 1/k$. But, I don't see why my proof is incorrect, so I don't see how that would fix it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your proof is essentially fine. The countability issue is on $\epsilon$. Your proof works for a fixed $\epsilon>0$, but how extend it to all $\epsilon>0$?

Here is how to solve it.

Let $A_{n,m} = \{x : |f_n(x) - f(x)| > \frac{1}{m}\}$ and let $[f_n \nrightarrow f]$ be the set of $x$ where $f_n(x)$ does not converge to $f$. It is easy to see that 
$$[f_n \nrightarrow f] = \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_{k,m}$$

Since, for all $m$,  $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \mu(A_{n,m}) < \infty$, by Borel-Cantelli, we have that 
$$\mu \left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_{k,m} \right)=0$$

So we have 
$$\mu([f_n \nrightarrow f]) = \mu \left (\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_{k,m}\right)=0$$

So $f_n \to f$ a.e.

Comment: I can follow all of the steps of your proof, but I guess I still don't see why letting $\epsilon \to 0$ at the end of my version doesn't work, would you be able to explain that to me? I'm sorry, I know I am being very oblivious here...

Comment: @gesa An uncountable union of sets of measure 0 may not have measure 0.  So if you keep $\epsilon$ in $\mathbb{R}$, you will not be able to conclude $\mu(f_n\nrightarrow f])=0$.  That is why we need the "trick" to replace $\epsilon$ by $\frac{1}{m}$.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_n = \{x : |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geqslant\epsilon\}$. By Borel Cantelli lemma, we have
$$
\sum^\infty_{n=1} \mu(\{x : |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geqslant \epsilon\}) < \infty\implies\mu(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k)=0
$$
Since
$$
x\in\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k\iff x\in A_n \hspace{3 mm}\text{infinitely often}
$$
Which means that there are infinitely many $n$ that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| \geqslant\epsilon\,$ or $\,f_n(x) \nrightarrow f(x)$. So we have $f_n \to f$ a.e.

Comment: No, this only shows that $A_n$ doesn't occur infinitely often for a fixed $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: $x\in A_n$ infinitely often means that there are infinite $n$ such that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| \geqslant\epsilon$, which also means that $f_n(x)\nrightarrow  f(x).$

Comment: Your chosen $x$ occurs in $A_n$ infinitely often for fixed $\epsilon$.  However, there are $x$ which occur in $A_n$ infinitely often for a different $\epsilon$. To conclude that $f_n\rightarrow f$ almost everywhere, you need to show the entire set of such $x$ has measure 0, which cannot immediately be done here as it would not necessarily be a countable union of measure 0 sets. See gesa's answer.

Comment: It is same as $\epsilon-N$ formula for limit. The key is that for one $\epsilon$, if $x_0$ occurs in $A_n$ infinitely often, then $f_n(x_0)$ diverges from $f(x_0)$.